# nextjs: my dynamic routes doesn't work after i use rewrites

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

this is my project structure and it's work before i add rewrites to my project

[image]

-dashboard
--admin
--page.tsx
---[adminId]
---page.tsx

--cars
--page.tsx
---[carId]
---page.tsx

-login
-- page.tsx

i can access /dashboard/admin, /dashboard/admin/1, /dashboard/cars, /dashboard/cars/1, /login

but when i add

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    formats: ["image/webp"],
  },
/// ============== don't have this it can access dynamic but i want to use it
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        destination: "/app/:path*",
      },
    ];
  },
/// =============== don't have this it can access dynamic but i want to use it

  assetPrefix: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/app/" : "",
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    basePath: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Now It's can only access 
/dashboard/admin, /dashboard/cars, /login

I can not access to /dashboard/admin/1, /dashboard/cars/1,  any more

[image]

How can i fix this, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, your are missing to add the dynamic segmentations like `[adminId]` and `[carId]` you can add these rules like this and make sure to add `app` folder otherwise you get not found.

also use `redirect()` instead of `rewrites()`.

```
    {
        source: "/dashboard/admin/:adminId",
        destination: "/app/dashboard/admin/:adminId",
        permanent: false,
    },
    {
        source: "/dashboard/cars/:carId",
        destination: "/app/dashboard/cars/:carId",
        permanent: false,
    }
```

do not add `path*` which will make endless redirects to `/app/app/app`

```
    {
        source: "/:path*",
        destination: "/app/:path*",
    },
```